# Installed Ubuntu on same partition as Windows 7. How can I unistall?

Tags: uninstall

I would like to unistall Linux completely. I will then put Ubuntu on my new computer, as I was just testing it before my custom rig came in.

TIA.

Comment: will you please edit and add `Disk Management` screen shot.

Comment: How you installed Ubuntu using .iso or wubi?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reinstall Windows, since installing Ubuntu onto the same partition will have overwritten the data Windows needs to work.  If you don't like that, you might try to use a program such as GParted to see if you can recover your Windows data